# Do websocket messages get cached if using Spring + SockJS + STOMP? If not, how to detect network disconnect?

Tags: angular, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I've got different parts of a page being updated at different times by websocket messages. If the network connection to the server fails for any reason (for any period of seconds to days) I need to get the page back into the correct state.
I'm using Spring websockets on the backend and SockJS and STOMP.js on the front end (built in Angular).

Q 1. Does any part of this cache the websocket messages being sent (I only use websockets one way, from server to client) and then detect a network failure and send the stored messages when the connection is restored? (so this scenario would automatically put the page back into the correct state)

Q 2. Otherwise, I need to detect a loss of network connection somehow - how to do this exactly?
(I would then trigger a full page reload from the front end - that's the bit I can do easily)

My backend is in Groovy, using Spring Websockets i.e.:

```
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate
SimpMessagingTemplate brokerMessagingTemplate
brokerMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend('/topic/updatepage', pageComponentMessage)
```

with this for config:

```
@CompileStatic
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class MySocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry messageBrokerRegistry) {
        messageBrokerRegistry.enableSimpleBroker "/queue", "/topic"
        messageBrokerRegistry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes "/app"
    }

    @Override
    void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/stomp").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS()
    }

    @Bean
    GrailsSimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler grailsSimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler(
        SubscribableChannel clientInboundChannel,
        MessageChannel clientOutboundChannel,
        SimpMessageSendingOperations brokerMessagingTemplate
    ) {
        def handler = new GrailsSimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler(clientInboundChannel, clientOutboundChannel, brokerMessagingTemplate)
        handler.destinationPrefixes = ["/app"]
        return handler
    }

    @Bean
    GrailsWebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler grailsWebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler(
        SubscribableChannel clientInboundChannel,
        MessageChannel clientOutboundChannel,
        SimpMessageSendingOperations brokerMessagingTemplate
    ) {
        def handler = new GrailsWebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler(clientInboundChannel, clientOutboundChannel, brokerMessagingTemplate)
        handler.destinationPrefixes = ["/app"]
        return handler
    }

}
```

and front end Angular code:

```
export class MyWSService {
  private sockjsclient = null; // SockJS socket that connects to the server (preferably using a WebSocket)
  private stompClient = null; // Stomp client that handles sending messages over the WebSocket

  subscribeToTopic(topic: string, subInstance: any, callbackfn): any { 

    // SockJS socket connection does not exist yet, set it up:
    if(!this.sockjsclient) {
      this.sockjsclient = new SockJS(myWebsocketUrl);
    }

    // If STOMP instance (to send messages over the socket) does not exist yet, set it up:
    if(!this.stompClient) {

      this.stompClient = Stomp.over(this.sockjsclient);

      this.stompClient.connect({}, () => {

        subInstance.wsSubscription = this.stompClient.subscribe(topic, (message) => callbackfn(message));
      })
    }
    // STOMP instance already exists, so use that existing connection:
    else {
        subInstance.wsSubscription = this.stompClient.subscribe(topic, (message) => callbackfn(message));
      }
  }

  unsubscribeFromTopic(subscription: any) {
    subscription.unsubscribe(); // Unsubscribe from topic
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is already on a theoretical level. Even if you would've a caching in place you weren't able to know how long you need to retain them.

What I did in a project to receive this functionality is subscribing all users to their dedicated user queue and configuring RabbitMQ in a way that the queues would expire only after a certain amount of time. With that approach - and since the user queue has only one subscriber - the message that wasn't delivered would simply stay in the queue until the respective user fetches it. On client side you can establish a new websocket connection and subscriptions as soon as you experience a connection loss (through missing heart beats). And as soon as you subscribed you'd receive the message you missed.

In order to configure the user queues in RabbitMQ I implemented a `ChannelInterceptor` that reacts on `SUBSCRIBE` frames:

```java
public class SubscribeInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

    private static final int EXPIRE_IN_MILLISECONDS = 30 * 1000;

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(@NonNull Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        if (accessor.getCommand() == StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE) {
            String username = accessor.getUser().getName();
            String queueName = Stream.of(accessor.getDestination().split("/"))
                    .reduce((f, s) -> s)
                    .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

            accessor.setNativeHeader("x-queue-name", String.format("%s_%s", username, queueName));
            accessor.setNativeHeader("x-expires", Integer.toString(EXPIRE_IN_MILLISECONDS));
            accessor.setNativeHeader("durable", "true");
            accessor.setNativeHeader("auto-delete", "false");
            return MessageBuilder.createMessage(message.getPayload(), accessor.getMessageHeaders());
        }
        return message;

    }
}
```